# Update smarty variable via ajax using twbs Pagination plugin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, smarty

I am using twbs pagination plugin, and on each click on the page number, an ajax call is fired and 10 results per page are fetched.
On the page upload, first 10 results are fetched and assigned to a smarty variable.

Here is the tpl file. I am assigning the fetched array from php to the variable batchesData and iterating it using a foreach loop to display it in tabular form

```
 <table class="table table-striped projects tablesorter" 
  id="batchTable" style="font-size: 13px;">
 <th>
 .....
 .....
 </th>
 <tbody>
 {if !empty($batchesData)}
 {foreach from = $batchesData key = filter item = value}
 <tr>
 ......
 ......
 </tr>
 {/foreach}
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Now on page click, here is my js code, I can fetch the array according to the page no from php but how do I update it because I guess smarty execution is done way before the ajax calls. Please suggest

```
    $(function () {
        window.pagObj = $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
            totalPages: 35,
            visiblePages: 10,
            onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/mbatch/batch/listBatch',
                    data : {
                        page: page,
                    },
                    beforeSend : function() {

                    },
                    success : function(response) {
                    /* Handling */
                    },
                    error : function(data) {
                        new PNotify({
                            title: 'Notice',
                            text: JSON.parse(data.responseText).message,
                            type: 'error',
                            styling: 'bootstrap3'
                        }); 
                    }
                });
            }
        }).on('page', function (event, page) {
        });
    });
```

Any leads would be highly appreciated. Here is the plugin link
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Customizable-Pagination-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Twbs-Pagination/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this  :

```
     $(function () {
    window.pagObj = $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: 35,
        visiblePages: 10,
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : '/mbatch/batch/listBatch',
                data : {
                    page: page,
                },
                beforeSend : function() {

                },
                success : function(response) {
                $("#batchTable").empty();//clearing the current table rows
                var dataRes=JSON.parse(response);
                var resultCount=dataRes.length; //Assuming result set in array form.
                //now creating row for each result set and appending to table
                $.each(dataRes,function(index,value){
                $("#batchTable").append("<tr>
               <td>"+
              value.item1+" 
              </td>
              <td>"+
              value.item2+"
              </td>
               </tr>")
                })
                },
                error : function(data) {
                    new PNotify({
                        title: 'Notice',
                        text: JSON.parse(data.responseText).message,
                        type: 'error',
                        styling: 'bootstrap3'
                    }); 
                }
            });
        }
    }).on('page', function (event, page) {
    });
});
```

Assuming your response will be in json format. Set your format accordingly in the the `success` function

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the obvious solution but I wanted something where in I can update/refresh my smarty variables.

Since there are many conditional statements in my table, so appending html via javascript would be a pain

Comment: smarty variables once rendered are nothing converted to plain htmls.
Please clear your concept on this : smarty variables are server side variables, and javascript runs on client side once server has dumped all the data to html page. There is no way javascript can update smarty variables.